# how to solve time issue in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

My 'user` table  looks likes following..

```
 id   |   name  |   time

 1    |    a1   |  2012-11-15 06:20:28

 2    |    a2   |  2012-11-14 06:20:28

 3    |    a3   |  2012-11-13 06:20:28
```

Now my problem is , how can I get the user detail whose time is in between present or 30 
second less than present time..

I tried..

```
"SELECT * 

FROM user

WHERE strtotime(user_session.session_timestamp)-30 < ".time().")";
```

its not working... It will throw syntax error

please help me to solve the issue

Comment: `strtotime()` is  PHP function - not MySQL...

Comment: it throws a syntax error since `strtotime` is a php function.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds

Comment: @ alfasin and @ luchosrock - please help  me to write in mysql

Comment: @abhi Jason McCreary already answered!

Answer (score 5):

No need for PHP. You can use the [MySQL Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE time BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 SECOND) AND NOW();
```

**Note:** This query is not *optimized* as the date function prevent the query from being cached. If this is a large concern, then using the PHP equivalent may be more performant.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime() is a PHP function, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way.  You need to do two different `SELECT` statements.  One to collect the `user_session.session_timestamp`.  Call the PHP `strtotime()` function `-30` then use that variable in this current `SELECT` statement.  Depending on how you have this setup you may be using a `foreach( $array as $key => $value)` to step through and run as many selects as you need to get individual returns.  The many problem is the PHP function being used in a SQL statement.

Or do what Jason said!  Pure SQL is always better, but I assumed you need or wanted to use PHP for some reason, there are some times important reasons for needing access to the data in PHP.